# Change [email from] for Hudson notification emails

Tags: jenkins, hudson

Currently, Hudson will send out the emails for failed builds and such from 
the email address setup as the Hudson administrator. Is the admin email 
address used for anything else, like error messages from Hudson or anything? 
I would like to change the address to something else so people quit thinking 
that I am sending them the build failure messages.

Or, is there a way I can have two different emails setup in hudson, one for Admin and one used for sending email notification.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any emails that are sent to specifically to the Hudson system administrator. It is used mostly in the notification emails.

Go to

- **Manage Hudson**
- **Configure System**
- Scroll down to **E-mail Notification**
- Change **System Admin E-mail Address** to whatever you want

If you are using [Email-ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin), you can also change the default `Reply To List` email address.

Ideally, your **system admin** address would be something like `hudson@company.com` (doesn't have to be a real address), while the **reply-to** address should be your actual email address so that users can reach you.

Comment: Thanks but, I already mentioned in question, I don't want to change System Admin Email address. I want to change email using which notifications hudson sent out.

Comment: The System Admin email address is used for nothing *but* sending build notification emails. You don't want your real email address in there (as you said), instead you should have a `"hudson@company.com"` or whatever identifying your build server. If you are using [Email-ext](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin), you can change the dafault `reply-to` address to your personal one.

Comment: Can we do this using jenkins CLI or API , as we need to change system Admin E-mail Address programmatically ? Please share if possible.

Comment: Again, look at Email-ext plugin, it can run pre-send scripts, which can change the recipients/senders and many other things. I have not seen a CLI option to directly change the email